# Binding objects in Thymeleaf - SpringBoot

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializr, using embedded Tomcat + Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used :

Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE, Tomcat Embed 8.5.6, Maven 3, Java 8

I have this class

```
public class AlarmNotification {

    private Long id;

    private Action action;

    private Application aplication;

    private Device device;

    private TimeLapse timeLapse;

    private Guardian guardian;

    private List<SystemAlarm.Level> level;

    ...
}
```

and this template

```
<form class="form-style-9" action="#" th:action="@{/alarmNotification/save}" th:object="${alarmNotification}" method="post">
    <ul>
    <li>

       <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"       />

        <select name="device" class="field-style field-split align-left">
        <option value="ANDROID">ANDROID</option>
        <option value="IOS">IOS</option>
    </select>
       <select th:field="*{guardian}">
         <option th:each="guardian : ${guardians}" 
             th:value="${guardian.id}" 
             th:text="${guardian.name}"></option>
    </select>   
    </li>   
    <li>
       <select th:field="*{timeLapse}">
         <option th:each="timeLapse : ${timeLapses}" 
            th:value="${timeLapse.id}"
             th:text="${timeLapse.description}"></option>
    </select>   
    </li>
     <li>
       <select th:field="*{level}" multiple="multiple">
         <option th:each="level : ${alarmLevels}" 
             th:value="${level}" 
             th:text="${level}"></option>
    </select> 
    </li>
    <li>        
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" value="SAVE" />
    </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

and the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/save" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveAlarmNotification (@Valid AlarmNotification alarmNotification, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) throws DataAccessException, SQLException {

        System.out.println  ("<-------------------------------------->");
        System.out.println  (alarmNotification);
        System.out.println  ("<-------------------------------------->");
..
}
```

but all the values of the object alarmNotification are null except the device and the level:

```
 AlarmNotification [id=null, action=null, aplication=null,
 device=Device [id=null, deviceKey=ANDROID], 
timeLapse=null, guardian=null, 
level=[HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that in your select tags the th:value is not correct, the id is not set correctly.

ie for the guardian it should be like this

```
<select th:field="*{guardian}">
      <option th:each="guardian : ${guardians}" 
             th:value="${guardian.id}" 
             th:text="${guardian.name}"></option>
</select>
```

for the timeLapse is should be declared like that

```
<select th:field="*{timeLapse}">
     <option th:each="timeLapse : ${timeLapses}" 
         th:value="${timeLapse.id}" 
         th:text="${timeLapse.description}"></option>
</select>
```

and for the level I think that you passed the wrong field ie it might look like that

```
<select th:field="*{level}" multiple="multiple">
             <option th:each="level : ${alarmLevels}" 
                 th:value="${level}" 
                 th:text="${level}"></option>
        </select>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Any idea why this is [not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306080/runtimeexception-memberaccess-implementation-must-be-provided)?